# how to deal with strange chars in selenium? 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0:

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, unicode, encoding

im trying to send keys with spanish accents in selenium, what im doing is sending strings via a array with various entrys, here is the line where it get stucks.

```
["Electrodomésticos", "Otros electrodomésticos", ["sensorhumo.jpg"], "Sensor de humo inalámbrico independiente.", "-Frecuencia: 433Mhz. -Codigo de trabajo: 2262. -Alacance inalámbrico: 80 mts con línea de vista. ", "59000", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"],
```

when i send this part:

"-Frecuencia: 433Mhz. -Codigo de trabajo: 2262. -Alacance inalámbrico: 80 mts con línea de vista. "

to this code:

```
    descripcion=".//*[@id='field-description']"
    descripciontext=str(array3[i][x])
    x=x+1
    descripcionelement = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(descripcion))
    descripcionelement.send_keys(descripciontext)
```

it throws this message:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0:
>   unexpected end of data

it only works if i remove the accents from this part and i tried using decode.

Comment: convert unicode and send -- myunicode = u"-Frecuencia: 433Mhz. -Codigo de trabajo: 2262. -Alacance inalámbrico: 80 mts con línea de vista."   Now use send_keys.

Comment: can you give an example, i dont understand your comment.

Comment: descripciontext = u"-Frecuencia: 433Mhz. -Codigo de trabajo: 2262. -Alacance inalámbrico: 80 mts con línea de vista."          and now            descripcionelement.send_keys(descripciontext)

Comment: @SIslam thanks a lot it worked, why didnt you post it as anwser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle unicode in selenium-sendkeys, unicode casting is needed, to convert bytes into unicode use one of the ways-

> descripciontext = "-Frecuencia: 433Mhz. -Codigo de trabajo: 2262.
>   -Alacance inalámbrico: 80 mts con línea de vista."

```
Unicode (by manual):     descripciontext = u"-Frecuencia: 433Mhz. -Codigo de trabajo: 2262. -Alacance inalámbrico: 80 mts con línea de vista."
```

Or

```
Unicode (by automatic decoding):     descripciontext = unicode(descripciontext.decode("iso-8859-4"))
```

Now use send_keys

```
descripcionelement.send_keys(descripciontext)
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap `unicode()` around `descripciontext.decode("iso-8859-4")` - `decode()` will return a Unicode string anyway

Answer (score 2):

I've stumbled with this error myself, when I was trying to send something like 'España' in a select option inside a form.

The accepted answer is right, the best approach is to send values in unicode.

I'll leave here a short easy code, that transforms the value that is sent, either str or unicode, in a transparent way

```
def _convert(param):
    if isinstance(param, str):
        return param.decode('utf-8')
    else:
        return param

# both examples will work
parameter = 'España'
driver_element.send_keys(_convert(parameter)) 

unicode_parameter = u'España'
driver_element.send_keys(_convert(parameter))
```